# How to implement state syncing via versioning in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, concurrency, race-condition

The API returns the following from several different sources:

```
{
  data: {'...'},
  version: 56
}
```

The idea is to only keep the most recent version:

```
// Our local state
var localDocument = {
  data: null,
  version: -1
};

var updateIfCurrent(document) {
  if (document.version > localDocument.version) {
    localDocument = document;
  }
}

$http.get('/foo', updateIfCurrent);
$http.get('/bar', updateIfCurrent);
```

So if any HTTP call returns an outdated version of the document, we don't replace our more current state.

However, lets imagine that `localDocument.version = 1`. Two updateIfCurrent calls come in with C1: `document.version = 2` and C2 `document.version = 3`. Is it possible that they both pass the `localDocument.version > document.version`, and `C2` finishes first and then `C1` finishes resulting in `document.version = 2` and not `document.version = 3`, as intended?

If yes, how to fix this?

Comment: "Is it possible that they both pass the `localDocument.version > document.version`...?" -- No, I don't see how that would be possible. JavaScript can only run one function at a time; any JS "race condition" deals with which functions gets to run first. All synchronous function execution is atomic, so whichever function runs first will completely finish before the next one begins.

Comment: @apsillers: Could this vary by JS engine implementation or is this guaranteed across different implementations?

Comment: I would happily accept your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that they both pass the `localDocument.version > document.version`...?

No, I don't see how that would be possible. JavaScript can only run one function at a time. Any "race condition" in JavaScript deals with which function gets to run first. All synchronous function execution is atomic, so whichever function runs first will completely finish before the next one begins.

Therefore, you are guaranteed that your second check for `localDocument.version > document.version` runs only after first function has completely finished.

> Could this vary by JS engine implementation or is this guaranteed across different implementations?

Technically speaking, no language specification requires JavaScript to be single-threaded. *Practically* speaking, there does not exist any multithreaded JavaScript engine (except for engines that support sandboxed Worker-style threads, which cannot cause race conditions). Any engine that did use multithreading to handle asynchronous code would fail to handle a vast amount of existing JS code; no one would reasonably expect code written for a single-threaded JS environment to work correctly in a multithreaded environment. Such an engine would likely also have to extend the language to include locking mechanisms and atomic operations.